# Верстка блока с изображением в ромбе

Tags: html, css, svg

Есть такой блок:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Изображение без фона (.png) внутри прозрачного ромба с градиентом. Нижняя часть ромба закрывает изображение, верхняя часть попадает под изображение. И все это на неоднородном фоне.

Пытаюсь разделить ромб на 2 части (верхнюю, нижнюю), но происходит наложение, которое заметно:

```css
.container {
  background: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1470071459604-3b5ec3a7fe05?dpr=1&auto=compress,format&fit=crop&w=1440&h=&q=80&cs=tinysrgb&crop=) center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
}

.photo {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 0 0 0 -50px;  
}

.photo img {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 3;
}

.item {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
}

.up:after,
.up:before,
.bottom:after,
.bottom:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
}

.bottom:after,
.bottom:before {  
  bottom: 76px;
  z-index: 5;
  opacity: .8;
}

.bottom:after {  
  right: -14px;  
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(231,111,5,1) 0%, rgba(238,172,17,1) 100%);
}

.bottom:before {
  left: -14px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  background: linear-gradient(to left, rgba(231,111,5,1) 0%, rgba(238,172,17,1) 100%);
}

.up:after,
.up:before {
  top: 76px;
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: .8;
}

.up:after {  
  right: -14px;  
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(231,111,5,1) 0%, rgba(238,172,17,1) 100%);
}

.up:before {
  left: -14px;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  background: linear-gradient(to left, rgba(231,111,5,1) 0%, rgba(238,172,17,1) 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">    
    <div class="up"></div>
    <div class="photo">
      <img src="https://avatanplus.com/files/resources/mid/576e6fa55f92315587641e0f.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="bottom"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Вопрос:** Какие есть варианты верстки таких блоков (чтобы изображение как бы *выглядывало* из геометрической фигуры), создавая *эффект объема*?

**P.S:** возможно есть простые варианты с использованием `svg`.

Comment: А нарезать ромб на две png не вариант?

Comment: @Cheg, тогда проще сделать картинку и с ромбом и с фигурой внутри )

Comment: @Cheg, интересует именно верстка, вырезать все можно, но не нужно

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Осталось лишь поиграться с размерами и позицией:

```css
.container {
  background: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1470071459604-3b5ec3a7fe05?dpr=1&auto=compress,format&fit=crop&w=1440&h=&q=80&cs=tinysrgb&crop=) center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
}

.photo {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.photo_inner {
  position: absolute;
  left: 20px;
  bottom: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.photo_border-back,
.photo_border-front {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.photo_border-back:before,
.photo_border-back:after,
.photo_border-front:before,
.photo_border-front:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #000;
}

.photo_border-back:before,
.photo_border-back:after {
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.photo_border-back:before { clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, calc(100% - 20px) 100%, 20px 100%); }
.photo_border-back:after { clip-path: polygon(0 20px, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 calc(100% - 20px)); }
.photo_border-front:before { clip-path: polygon(20px 0, calc(100% - 20px) 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%); }
.photo_border-front:after { clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 20px, 100% calc(100% - 20px), 0 100%); }

.photo_border-front:before,
.photo_border-front:after {
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.photo_border-back:before,
.photo_border-front:before {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
}

.photo_border-back:after,
.photo_border-front:after {
  width: 20px;
  height: 100%;
}

.photo_border-back:before,
.photo_border-back:after {
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255,106,0,.8) -100%, rgba(255,220,0,.8) 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255,106,0,.8) -100%,rgba(255,220,0,.8) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255,106,0,.8) -100%,rgba(255,220,0,.8) 100%);
}

.photo_border-front:before,
.photo_border-front:after {
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255,106,0,.8) 1%, rgba(255,220,0,.8) 200%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255,106,0,.8) 1%,rgba(255,220,0,.8) 200%);
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255,106,0,.8) 1%,rgba(255,220,0,.8) 200%);
}

.photo_item {
  position: relative;
  left: -50%;
  top: 0;
  margin: 0 0 20px 40px;
  width: 500px;
  transform-origin: 50% 100%;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="photo">
    <div class="photo_border-back"></div>
    <div class="photo_inner">
      <img src="https://avatanplus.com/files/resources/mid/576e6fa55f92315587641e0f.png" alt="" class="photo_item">
    </div>
    <div class="photo_border-front"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: А чем этот вариант отличается от варианта в вопросе?)

Comment: @Cheg, тем что он обрезает?

Comment: @HamSter, обновил. Используется `clip-path` не знаю что там по полифилам для него, ибо поддержка вроде неочень.

Comment: @MedvedevDev, да с поддержкой там не очень, но и дизайн современный, соответственно плюшки верстки тоже современные пойдут) Спасибо, этот вариант мне больше нравится, как раз из-за обрезки.

Answer (score 2):

Вариант с `clip-path`:

```css
.container {
  background: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1470071459604-3b5ec3a7fe05?dpr=1&auto=compress,format&fit=crop&w=1440&h=&q=80&cs=tinysrgb&crop=) center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
}

.photo {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 0 0 0 -50px;
}

.photo img {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 3;
}

.item {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
}

.up,
.bottom {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  left: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(231, 111, 5, 1) 0%, rgba(238, 172, 17, 1) 100%);
  opacity: .8;
}

.up {
  top: 0;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 100%, 5% 100%, 50% 10%, 95% 100%, 100% 100%, 50% 0);
  clip-path: polygon(0 100%, 5% 100%, 50% 10%, 95% 100%, 100% 100%, 50% 0);
}

.bottom {
  bottom: 0;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(5% 0, 0 0, 50% 100%, 100% 0, 95% 0, 50% 90%);
  clip-path: polygon(5% 0, 0 0, 50% 100%, 100% 0, 95% 0, 50% 90%);
  z-index: 4;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="up"></div>
    <div class="photo">
      <img src="https://avatanplus.com/files/resources/mid/576e6fa55f92315587641e0f.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="bottom"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Поддержка](http://caniuse.com/#search=clip-path) браузерами.

Вместо процентных значений можно также использовать и значения в пикселях.

Вот [тут](http://bennettfeely.com/clippy/) можно "поиграться" с формами.

Comment: Спасибо, отличный вариант решения задачи!